# Why is the decision tree giving 100% accuracy and whole numbers on the precision and recall values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, spyder

I have a file with 5000 game reviews on amazon and I am trying to calculate the review scores and get results, however when I run the program I am getting whole numbers on precision and recall, I have tried to change the size of the training data already to no avail, can anybody see why the code is not working correctly?

```
"""@author: bradl"""

# Importing the required packages 
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score 
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report 

# Function importing Dataset 
def importdata(): 

    balance_data = pd.read_csv( 
'file:///D:/bradl/Downloads/csv/csv/reviews_Video_Games_test.csv',sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode') 

    # Printing the dataswet shape 
    print ("Dataset Length: ", len(balance_data)) 
    print ("Dataset Shape: ", balance_data.shape) 

    # Printing the dataset obseravtions 
    print ("Dataset: ",balance_data.head()) 
    return balance_data 

# Function to split the dataset 
def splitdataset(balance_data): 

    # Separating the target variable 
    X = balance_data.values[:, 1:5] 
    Y = balance_data.values[:, 0] 

    # Splitting the dataset into train and test 
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( 
    X, Y, test_size = 0.7, random_state = 100) 

    return X, Y, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test 

# Function to perform training with giniIndex. 
def train_using_gini(X_train, X_test, y_train): 

    # Creating the classifier object 
    clf_gini = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "gini", 
            random_state = 100,max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5) 

    # Performing training 
    clf_gini.fit(X_train, y_train) 
    return clf_gini 

# Function to perform training with entropy. 
def tarin_using_entropy(X_train, X_test, y_train): 

    # Decision tree with entropy 
    clf_entropy = DecisionTreeClassifier( 
            criterion = "entropy", random_state = 100, 
            max_depth = 3, min_samples_leaf = 5) 

    # Performing training 
    clf_entropy.fit(X_train, y_train) 
    return clf_entropy 


# Function to make predictions 
def prediction(X_test, clf_object): 

    # Predicton on test with giniIndex 
    y_pred = clf_object.predict(X_test) 
    print("Predicted values:") 
    print(y_pred) 
    return y_pred 

# Function to calculate accuracy 
def cal_accuracy(y_test, y_pred): 

    print("Confusion Matrix: ", 
        confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)) 

    print ("Accuracy : ", 
    accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)*100) 

    print("Report : ", 
    classification_report(y_test, y_pred)) 

# Driver code 
def main(): 

    # Building Phase 
    data = importdata() 
    X, Y, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = splitdataset(data) 
    clf_gini = train_using_gini(X_train, X_test, y_train) 
    clf_entropy = tarin_using_entropy(X_train, X_test, y_train) 

    # Operational Phase 
    print("Results Using Gini Index:") 

    # Prediction using gini 
    y_pred_gini = prediction(X_test, clf_gini) 
    cal_accuracy(y_test, y_pred_gini) 

    print("Results Using Entropy:") 
    # Prediction using entropy 
    y_pred_entropy = prediction(X_test, clf_entropy) 
    cal_accuracy(y_test, y_pred_entropy) 


# Calling main function 
if __name__=="__main__": 
    main()
```

This is the result I get:

```
Results Using Entropy:
Predicted values:
['0' '0' '0' ... '0' '0' '0']
Confusion Matrix:  [[3500]]
Accuracy :  100.0
Report :                precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00      3500

    accuracy                           1.00      3500
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00      3500
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00      3500
```

Comment: u are getting `precision,recall & f1-score` all as `1.00`, whats the issue?

Comment: Because it's not accurate according to the data set which leads me to believe the program is not reading the data properly

Comment: you only have one class here?, if so why do need a predictio?

Comment: Its for a coursework, I know its absolutely pointless but this is what they want me to do and then do a K nearest neighbor on the same data set

Comment: `Because it's not accurate according to the data`, can you explain? `precision,recall & f1-score` of `1.00` is the max you can get. refer [classification_report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)

Comment: I wanted it to basically figure out which reviews are good, bad or neutral using words like bad and review scores this has just counted the review scores

Comment: After you split your dataset, please print the unique values in y_train and share the output with us: After `X, Y, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = splitdataset(data)`, add `print("training unique values:",y_train.unique(),"test unique values",y_test.unique())`.

Comment: Something is wrong with your target variable. You only have one possible value for your dependent variable, based on your model output, which is 0. So of course your model will always predict correctly. You can confirm this by running `print(y_train.unique())` - which tells you how many unique values you have in your model - after you split your data. To make a good model, make sure your target variable has all the correct classes, which in your case would be good/bad/neutral review score I guess.